# Phantom type confusion?

Tags: haskell, phantom-types

I'm confused over the use of phantom types:

```
type Words = String
type Numbers = Int

data NonPhantom = NP1 Words | NP2 Numbers deriving (Show)

data Phantom a = P1 Words | P2 Numbers deriving (Show) 

nonPhantomFunction :: NonPhantom -> Int
nonPhantomFunction r = 100


phantomFunction :: Phantom Numbers -> Int
phantomFunction a = 2001


main = do
   print $ nonPhantomFunction (NP1 "sdsdds") --can also pass NP2 here! 
   print $ phantomFunction (P1 "sdsdsd") --This shouldn't work!?
```

I expect this code **NOT** to compile, as the `phantomFunction` explicitly states its expecting data type `Phantom` of `Numbers`.

However this compiles fine? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you want a GADT instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data Phantom a = P1 Words | P2 Numbers deriving (Show)
```

This makes `P1 "aa"` of any type of the form `Phantom a`, for any `a`, including `Numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit connection between the argument of a constructor and the type argument of the type that constructor belongs to. If you want the type denoted by the type argument to appear anywhere in the arguments of a constructor, you need to explicitly state it.

You can see this also in the following expressions:

```
Nothing
[]
```

The first one can create a `Maybe a`  for any `a` and the second a list `[a]` for any `a`.

Likewise

```
P1 "xyz"
```

from your example can make a `Phantom a` for any `a`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already explained that the type of your constructor

```
P1 :: Words -> Phantom a
```

means it is able to construct a value of type `P1 a` for *any* choice of `a`; in particular, for the choice of `a ~ Numbers`. This is why your function call

```
phantomFunction (P1 "sdsdsd")
```

typechecks.

Now, how do you solve this? I assume you would like `P1 :: Words -> Phantom Words`? GADTs allow you to constrain the type variables occurring in the type of the constructed value, by allowing you to write

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Phantom a where
    P1 :: Words -> Phantom Words
    P2 :: Numbers -> Phantom Numbers
```

This will

- Ensure `P1 _` has type `Phantom Words` so you can't construct a `Phantom Numbers` with it
- Allow functions that consume a `Phantom Words` to do exhaustive pattern matching by only matching on `P1`
- Allow functions that are polymorphic over `Phantom a` to refine their type based on pattern matching (this is the big one), so you can write e.g.

  ```
  dup :: Phantom a -> a
  dup (P1 ws) = ws ++ ws -- Here, we have to return a Words, and ws is a Words, so ++ will work
  dup (P2 n) = n + n -- Here, we have to return a Numbers, and x is a Numbers, so + will work
  ```